# At what point is SQL Server's is_policy_checked enforced?

Tags: sql-server, security

At what point is SQL Server's `is_policy_checked` enforced - just at next password change or at each login?

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/99262/1186

Comment: Also related: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32905714-check-policy-is-a-no-op-with-create-login-pass

Answer (score 0):

The [CHECK_POLICY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017) option is used to enforce Windows Password Policy restrictions and mechanisms for SQL Server logins. This applies when a login is created or when a password is changed for a SQL Server login as it affects the validity of a chosen password based on the setting state and the Windows password policy. It does not perform any validation or checks when a user logs on.

If you're trying to force passwords to be validated after enabling this option on existing logins, you should also enable the MUST_CHANGE option to force users to change their password on next login as the new passwords would then have to comply with the new policy.